# How do i delete a copied`System Volume Information`?

Tags: windows-7

I used robocopy to copy a drive. The folder is hidden and system which is annoying bc i need to change my folder properties to see it and i switch back so i dont delete system files in other folders unknowingly. But my main problem is.

How do i delete `System Volume Information`? Robocopy created it. I now dont need it. But its there and i cant remove the folder bc of it. How do i delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Doing this](https://superuser.com/questions/116625/recursively-change-owner-windows-7/116626#116626) worked. Note i also did the accepted answer first.