# Extract files from CSC (offline files) folder

Tags: windows-7, offline-files

Is there a way to extract files from the c:\windows\csc folder in Windows 7 professional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download the CSCCMD tool v1.1 from Microsoft Support (or try finding it on the Internet may be easier), and then follow the following support document from Microsoft using the /Extract switch (The syntax is near the bottom).

for example: csccmd /EXTRACT /RECURSE /TARGET:c:\csc-files

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884739

Comment: YOu can get the tool here: http://www.jacksontechnical.com/article.htm?id=34 or here: http://www.megaupload.com/?d=5EUO5R6K

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome, if we join our forces we can solve every tech problem EVER! ;) It is addicting though, racking up the points, I'll have a beer when I hit the 1000 mark! :)

Comment: @Ruairi Fullam LOL addicted...me too. I have only been a member for 36 days now. :) I want 20K.

Comment: I'm sorry, the file you link to does not work in Windows 7 professional: `the ordinal 54 could not be located in the dynamic link library CSCDLL.dll`

Comment: i thought i upvoted first and wanted to undo that. it wasn't meant to downvote. but i cannot undo the downvote now unless the answer is edited

Comment: @jao OK, thank you. Sorry for the over-reaction. Did you manage to get it to work, if not, what did you do? Let me know exactly where you downloaded it from, and how you used it, and I will try to replicate the results, and figure out why it did not work.

Comment: no it didn't work. i'm now trying to get ownership of all the files using takeown (http://superuser.com/questions/116625/recursively-change-owner-windows-7/116627#116627) see how that works

Comment: Are you still getting the DLL error or are you past that? Either way, you are on the right track.

Comment: by getting ownership using `takeown /f "c:\folder\subfolder" /r` command I was able to acces the files and copy them to a safe destination. (so how do i accept this answer, the answer doesn't really apply to this particular question but I still want to credit @Kcotreau for pointing me in the right direction)

Comment: You can still accept it. They will read the comments too.

Comment: Regarding Windows 7, note that it will still not work even if you use the CSCDLL.dll from Windows XP. It gives the error "csc is not enabled on this machine".

Answer (score 1):

**Working Solution**

On the command line:

```
vssadmin List Shadows
```

This will show you a list of your shadow copies (the shadow of the CSC folder will not be locked). Look for and copy the highest numbered original address.

Secondly we make a link to the shadow copy:

```
mklink /D C:\LatestShadow \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy417\
```

The rightmost part of that should be the original address you copied before

Next use robocopy to get all the files out of the cache

```
mkdir C:\CSC_copy
robocopy C:\LatestShadow\Windows\CSC C:\CSC_copy /E /COPY:DT
```

You should end up with a copy of all the cache files in C:\CSC_Copy.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to grant full access

```
cd %systemroot%
takeown /f csc /r /a /d y
icacls csc /grant Everyone:(F) /t /l /q
```

then reboot.

```
vssadmin List Shadows
```

This will show you a list of your shadow copies (the shadow of the CSC folder will not be locked). Look for and copy the highest numbered original address.
Secondly we make a link to the shadow copy:

```
mklink /D C:\LatestShadow \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy417\
```

The rightmost part of that should be the original address you copied before
Next use `robocopy` to get all the files out of the cache

```
mkdir C:\CSC_copy
robocopy C:\LatestShadow\Windows\CSC C:\CSC_copy /E /zb /copyall
```

then took ownership of the files in the `C:\CSC_Copy`