# Recursively change ownership to another user in windows

Tags: windows, permissions, ownership

In Windows (particularly, Windows server 2012) I have to change ownership of a folder with a bunch of subfolders and files.

Here: [recursively change owner windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/116625/recursively-change-owner-windows-7) (and in other places) people suggest to use 'takeown' command for that.
The problem is that I need to set another user as the owner, not myself. But I don't know their password, as well as I don't want to tell them the admin password so that they can run this command with the administrator privileges on their own.

When I tried to specify a target user to the 'takeown' command: `takeown /S 127.0.0.1 /U someuser /F somedir /R`, it has responded that the user credentials cannot be used for local connections.

How can I set another user as a directory/file owner recursively in Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A user doesn't need administrator rights to use `takeown` if you grant them the "Take Ownership" permission on the objects first. (This is `WO` in icacls, and is included in "Full Control" `F` set.)

```
:: Grant "Full Control" (inheritable):
icacls C:\foo /grant "DOM\user:(oi)(ci)f"

:: Or, grant "Write Owner" only (inheritable):
icacls C:\foo /grant "DOM\user:(oi)(ci)(wo,s)"

:: Now the user can takeown the folder.
```

In recent Windows versions, you can also use `icacls /setowner` to directly assign ownership to another user:

```
icacls C:\foo /setowner "DOM\user" /t /l
```

This is not part of `takeown` because it performs the actual change through a completely different operation than just taking ownership, and *does* require administrator rights regardless of what permissions you currently have on the file.

(Specifically, /setowner requires the "Back up files" and "Restore files" system-wide rights, which only Administrators and Backup Operators have by default. In comparison, takeown only uses the "Take ownership" system-wide right and/or the file-level permission.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've used `icacls /setowner`, and it has solved the issue.